# How many address bits are required to address 32 Mbyte of byte-addressable memory?

Tags: memory, byte, memory-address, bit

I found this question in one of my previous exam papers and I am not really sure if I got the right answer to it. As far as I see 2^15 is 32768 which is 32 MB so the answer could be 15 bits. But I think I'm missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

32768 bytes is not 32 Mb.

32 Mb = 32 * 1024Kb = 32 * 1024 * 1024 bytes = 2^5 * 2^10 * 2^10 = 2^25

That is, 33.554.432 bytes = 32 Mb.

So you will need, **at least 25 bits** to address a single byte in that memory scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Since 1MB = 10^6 bytes i.e. 2^20 bytes for 32 MB we have:

32 = 2^5 bytes
1MB = 2^20 bytes so,

32MB = 2^5 * 2^20 = 2^25 bytes,

BUT the question asks "How many address bits..." not bytes, therefore we multiply by 8 = 2^3 (because 1byte = 8bits), that is
32 Mbytes = 2^5 * 2^20 *2^3 = 2^28

Thus, 28 bits are needed.

Comment: When has any program addressed memory by the bit?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, some powers of 10. 32768<>32MB

1M is 2^20, 32 is 2^5, so you need 25 bits.